# Dividing one array of structures into 2 seperate arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm making a deck of cards, but I came across a problem. I want to divide one set (52 cards) into two, 26 cards in each deck.

I have functions to make each one of them, and to display them on the screen.  I used enums for both suits and face of the cards. I used enums inside structure too.

Everything works fine when I use functions in this order (code below):

1. `Deck_Creator`
2. `Deck_Shuffler`
3. `Deck1_Creator` (First 26 cards from shuffled main deck are passing into deck1)
4. `Display_Hand1` (Displays deck 1 - first 26 cards from 52 card deck, works fine)
5. `Deck2_Creator` (Second 26 cards from shuffled main deck)
6. `Display_Hand2` (Works fine).

Then in step 7 i want to display `Deck1`, but after using `Deck2_Creator`, everything messes up. My deck 1, suddenly looks like deck 2, shifted 1 place to the end of an array, and `deck1[0]` is the last value from `deck1`.

I tried both copying data from the main deck to `deck1`/`deck2`, and using `memcpy`, and I have no idea what else I can do. If you see a better, simpler way to divide one deck into two, I would like to hear it.

---

After dividing I want to make a queue, which I will use to make the card game "War": each person flips a card, then cards are compared, and the highest rank wins.

Here's my code:

```
#define SIZE 52
#define HALF_SIZE 26

using namespace std; // i can use only cin, and cout from c++

typedef enum Suit { Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, Clubs } Suit_t;
typedef enum Power { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace } Power_t;
```

```
typedef struct card {
    Suit_t suit;
    Power_t power;
}cards;

void Deck_Creator(cards* deck) {            // WORKS FINE
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        deck[i].suit = (Suit)(i / 13);
        deck[i].power = (Power)(i % 13);
    }
}

void Display_Deck(cards* deck) {           // WORKS FINE
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (deck[i].suit == 0) {
            cout << "Diamond ";
        }
        else if (deck[i].suit == 1) {
            cout << "Heart ";
        }
        else if (deck[i].suit == 2) {
            cout << "Spade ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Club ";
        }
        cout << " " << deck[i].power << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Deck_Shuffler(cards* deck) {
    int changer = 0;               // Index of changed card
    cards temp = {};             // Temporary holding place for changing
    srand(time(NULL));            // Function to get random numbers with current time
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        changer = rand() % SIZE;   // Generating random number from 0 to 51
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[changer];
        deck[changer] = temp;
    }
}

void Display_Hand_1(cards* deck1) {   // WORKS ONLY WITH PREVIOUS Deck1_Creator function

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        cout << deck1[i].suit;
        cout << " " << deck1[i].power;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Display_Hand_2(cards* deck2) {    // WORKS ONLY WITH PREVIOUS Deck2_Creator function

    for (int i = HALF_SIZE; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << deck2[i].suit;
        cout << " " << deck2[i].power << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Deck1_Creator(cards* deck, cards* deck1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HALF_SIZE; i++) {
        memcpy(&deck1[i], &deck[i], sizeof(cards));
    }

}

void Deck2_Creator(cards* deck, cards* deck2) {
    int i = HALF_SIZE;
    for (; i < SIZE; i++) {
        deck2[i] = deck[i];   // Simple copying struct array content into another array
    }

}

int main() {                  
    cards deck[SIZE];
    cards deck1[HALF_SIZE];
    cards deck2[HALF_SIZE];
    char choice;

    for(; ;) {  //Never ending loop
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            cout << endl << "Unshuffled deck: " << endl;
            Deck_Creator(deck);
            Display_Deck(deck);
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << endl << "Shuffled deck: " << endl;
            Deck_Shuffler(deck);
            Display_Deck(deck);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << endl << "Hand 1:" << endl;
            Deck1_Creator(deck, deck1);
            Display_Hand_1(deck1);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << endl << "Hand 2:" << endl;
            Deck2_Creator(deck, deck2);
            Display_Hand_2(deck2);
            break;
        case '5':
        //  Deck1_Creator(deck, deck1);
            Display_Hand_1(deck1);
            break;
        case '6':
            Display_Hand_2(deck2);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're actually using C++, not C. (Namespaces and cout/cin do not exist in C.) Please use correct language tags.

Comment: @IanAbbott I think the comment after `using namespace std` is meant to say that `cout` and `cin` are the _only_ C++ constructs in use here; the rest should be C. That said, it would be easier to debug this if it was in pure C and could be compiled as such. I think it would just need to use `printf` and `getchar` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Deck2_Creator` you are copying to `deck2[HALF_SIZE]` onwards, but `deck2` is only `HALF_SIZE` elements long to start with, so these assignments are out of bounds. You probably want to copy to `deck2[0]` onwards like this:

```
void Deck2_Creator(cards* deck, cards* deck2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HALF_SIZE; i++) {
        deck2[i] = deck[i + HALF_SIZE];
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, Tkanks for help :) Mistake so small, and so much time wasted for it :(